# How can we write the sentence '$x$ is a set' in the language of set theory

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

I am studying set theory. In most of the references on set theory such as the Jech's book, they start with the axioms of ZFC and the first-order language of set theory and eventually they start to talk about certain 'objects' called sets. I see a certain logic jump. 
I want to understand how is formally defined the sentence '$x$ is a set' from the first-order language. I understand that this sentence means that we can find some well-formed formula $\varphi(u)$ with a free variable $u$ where the sentence $(\exists x)\varphi(x)$ is true in ZFC. Am I right?

Comment: It is not possible with with "standard" $\mathsf{ZFC}$ because we have no predicate $\text{Set}(x)$. Every element of the domain is a *set*.

Comment: There are versions of set-tehory with *atoms* (or [urelements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement)) i.e. objects that are not set. In this case, we may have a predicate $\text {Ur}$ such that $\text {Ur}(x)$ holds iff $x$ is **not** a *set*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA As far as I see, in Jech's book, it starts with the axioms but no domain is introduced, then eventually they talk about certain objects sets. It is always necessary to have a domain?

Comment: Every "formal" theory pressuposes implicitly that it "speak about" something. Every set theory "speaks about" *sets*. The "domain" is the technical term of the formal semantics relative to a theory used to formalize the informal notion of "speaking about something".

Comment: It might be useful to think of the analogous question for more concrete theories; e.g. how do we say "is a natural number" in the context of Peano arithmetic (where *everything considered* is a natural number)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you work in standard set theory, *everything* is a set.

In other words, formulas in the language of set theory do cannot even be applied to things that are not sets.

So if you want a formula $\varphi(x)$ which is true when $x$ is a set and false if $x$ is not a set, this means that you want a $\varphi(x)$ that is always true, period. You can use any propositional tautology you want for that, such as $x\in x\to x\in x$, but that won't make you any wiser about *sets*.